# Is it safe to implement `std::marker::Unpin`?

Tags: rust, future

I am about to convert some code from futures-0.1 to futures-0.3 where the `poll()` methods require pinned data now.  Some of my structs are unpinnable which complicates the porting.  But there seems to exist an easy way by adding an `impl Unpin` for these classes.  Is this safe? What are the alternatives?

Example code:

```
extern crate futures;

use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{ Poll, Context };

struct InnerData {
    _pin: std::marker::PhantomPinned,
}

struct Stream {
}

struct Poller {
    _data: InnerData,
    file: Stream,
}

impl futures::stream::Stream for Stream {
    type Item = ();

    fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>, _cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        Poll::Pending
    }
}

impl Future for Poller {
    type Output = Result<(), ()>;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Self::Output>
    {
        use crate::futures::Stream;

        // here, rust fails with
        // error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::marker::PhantomPinned: std::marker::Unpin` is not satisfied in `Poller`  
        Pin::new(&mut self.get_mut().file).poll_next(cx).is_ready();

        Poll::Pending
    }
}

// Activating this seems to be an easy workaround...
// impl std::marker::Unpin for Poller {}

fn main() {
}
```

I use `futures-0.3.1` and `rust-1.40.0`.

Comment: I'd dare say that if this weren't safe, the trait itself would be `unsafe`, as `Send` or `Sync` are, but I also struggle to understand all this `Pin` business.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this safe?

Yes because marking `Poller` as `Unpin` is not transitive with regard to its fields. You still can't conjure a pinned `_data` field out of thin air. It is a compiler error if you try `Pin::new(&mut self.get_mut()._data)` since [`new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.new) is only available for `Pin<P>` if `<P as Deref>::Target` is `Unpin`:

```rust
impl<P> Pin<P> where
    P: Deref,
    <P as Deref>::Target: Unpin,
{
    pub fn new(pointer: P) -> Pin<P>
}
```

The Rust [`Pin` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html#pinning-is-not-structural-for-field) has a section to expand on this:

> Pinning is not structural for `field`
>
> What that type thinks about pinning is not relevant when no `Pin<&mut Field>` is ever created.

It is only unsafe if you do `impl std::marker::Unpin for InnerData {}`, which promises the compiler something untrue. It won't be able to stop you from writing `Pin::new(&mut self.get_mut()._data)` any more.

So this works:

```rust
impl Future for Poller {
    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        use futures::stream::Stream as _;
        Pin::new(&mut self.get_mut().file).poll_next(cx).is_ready();
        Poll::Pending
    }
}

impl std::marker::Unpin for Poller {}
```

> What are the alternatives?

There are third party crates such as `pin-project` to make this `Pin` business a tad easier:

```rust
use pin_project::pin_project;  // pin-project = "0.4.6"

#[pin_project]
struct Poller {
    _data: InnerData,
    #[pin]
    file: Stream,
}

impl Future for Poller {
    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        use futures::stream::Stream as _;
        let this = self.project();
        this.file.poll_next(cx).is_ready();
        Poll::Pending
    }
}
```